# Countif against a pre-defined value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to use countifs() to help narrow my parameters for counting, though I am unable to set a parameter based on something above in my code.

I have the user input a year and separately a month; I want to use this input in my countifs statement, though I am having no such luck.

For a sanity check, I input the specific month and year values and was able to get a correct answer.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Investigations()

'Return to Overview sheet before running as non-subsequent columns may receive output if viewing another sheet
Sheets("Overview").Select

'Define year and month
Dim zYear As Integer
    zYear = InputBox("Year (yyyy)")
Dim zMonth As Integer
    zMonth = InputBox("Month (mm)")

'Define zYear and zMonth on the spreadsheet so it can be referenced
Sheets("Investigations").Range("L1").Value = zYear
Sheets("Investigations").Range("M1").Value = zMonth

'Count of total minor investigations
Dim LastCol1 As Long
LastCol1 = Range("A12").End(xlToRight).Column
Sheets("Overview").Cells(12, LastCol1 + 1).Formula = "=countif(Investigations!H:H,""Low"")"

'Define and count minor investigations closed on time (<31 days), in the pre-defined year and month
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Investigations").Range("I1").Formula = "Time to Close (Days)"
Sheets("Investigations").Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=if(F2>0,abs(F2-E2),""N/A"")"
Sheets("Investigations").Range("J1").Formula = "Month of Closure"
Sheets("Investigations").Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=if(F2>0,month(F2),""N/A"")"
Sheets("Investigations").Range("K1").Formula = "Closed in Defined Month"
Sheets("Investigations").Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(J2=$M$1,TRUE,FALSE)"

'Count of closed minor investigation in pre-defined year and month
Sheets("Overview").Cells(13, LastCol1 + 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(Investigations!H:H,""Low"",Investigations!I:I,""<31"",Investigations!K:K,""True"")"


End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

---

Edit1:

There is not an error message with this.  The count returns zero when the code is run.  The sanity check returned 38 items (eliminated from >8k lines).  My issue is that I do not know how to appropriately reference the zMonth and zRange in my countif, since they don't actually exist on any sheet, just in the code.

Edit2:

Updated code to define zMonth and zYear on my investigations sheet.  Now I've a comparison column for this so I can avoid trying to call the code in a countif.  Still having issues getting this to work; my sanity check (completed on Investigations tab) states =COUNTIFS(H:H,"Low",I:I,"<31",K:K,"True") which gives a result of 38, while using Sheets("Overview").Cells(13, LastCol1 + 1).Formula = "=countifs(Investigations!H:H,""Low"",Investigations!I:I,""<31"",Investigations!K:K,""True"")" gives a value of 0.

Edit3:

Turns out I had a space in the final count string.  Works now.

Comment: Can you add the specific error and the line the error occurred on to your question text?

Comment: Added the following note:  There is not an error message with this. The count returns zero when the code is run. The sanity check returned 38 items (eliminated from >8k lines). My issue is that I do not know how to appropriately reference the zMonth and zRange in my countif, since they don't actually exist on any sheet, just in the code.

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out, and sorry I couldn't help more, got tied up at work. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find an answer to my original question and found a work-around by placing the zMonth and zYear on the sheet to be referenced by cell.